# Accessing method of a container from Django template

Tags: python, django

I have a Python object that is an instance of a subclass of container. So this object, `x`, can behave like `x['name']`. This object also has methods, say `x.bar()`.

How do I call `x.bar` from a Django template? In the template `x.bar` will always be evaluated as `x['bar']` first, which gives `None`.

The best I can think of is to create an object shadowing `x`, that does not have `getitem`. But I can't `delattr` `__getitem__`.

Any better ideas? Short of passing in results of those calls manually in context or a template tag.

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose I can create a proxy class and use __getattr__ to call methods in the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fundamental flaw in the way Django templates do expression evaluation. Look at the template tag [`{% expr -arbitrary-python-expression- %}`](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/9/) for a workaround. E.g. `{% expr x.bar(1,2,3) as snort %}` gives you a new variable in the current Context named `snort`.

Alternatively, you could try [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) templates. They are very close to Django's, but they allow full Python.

Note: Jinja2 is *not* the same templating system as Django's, and if you are using any page-embedded django app's that depend on the templating system, this may break them. That is not true for the `{% expr %}` tag.

Comment: I am not a fan of generic python expressions in templates, but I see what you mean here. This might be the only alternative.

Comment: @Overclocked: we use `expr` very conservatively; mostly in template areas that cache *big* formatted data. If the cache has expired (information not available in the view), then we cause the data fetch to happen inside of the template. This solved a major performance hit for us. We tried to pass in a curried function, but this hit a bug that went unfixed for years; Finally fixed in 1.3 ([#7153](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7153)).